# How to extract data from collection made by jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just a small example. I have 3 links, a button and a div:

```
<a href="#">AAA</a>
<a href="#">BBB</a>
<a href="#">CCC</a>
<button id="getResult">Get result</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now, when the button is pressed, I want to get the text from 3 links and insert them to the result div. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#getResult').click(function() {
            var links = $('a');
            $.each(links, function() {
                $('#result').append('<p>' + links.html() + '</p>');
            });
        }); // end click
    }); // end ready
</script>
```

I expect the result would be

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

But it is

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix this? If you have a better way to do this, could you tell me? I'm very new to jQuery. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
        $.each(links, function() {
            $('#result').append('<p>' + links.html() + '</p>');
```

with

```
        links.each(function() {
            $('#result').append('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
```

or simply

```
$('a').each(function() {
     $('#result').append('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
});
```

You were not using the iterated items, and you should use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over a jQuery collection.

Another more direct solution, resulting in only one change of the DOM (that's usually the costly opearion) would be this :

```
$('#result').html(
  $('a').map(function(){return '<p>'+this.innerHTML+'</p>'}).get().join('')
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `.each` function you call `links.html()` which only gets the html of the *first* element in the collection.  You mean to use `$(this).html()` (probably).

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xZymh/

By the way you could rewrite this to just use the `.html` method itself to do the appending:

```
$("a").html(function (_, html) {
    $("#result").append("<p>" + html + "</p>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xZymh/1/

Answer (score 1):

when in doubt make things simple.  You can do this without the need for the jQuery $.each statement.  Im not 100% but i think its being used incorrectly anyways.

instead of $.each try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
   var linkHtml = links[i].html();
   $('#result').append('<p>' + linksHtml + '</p>');  
}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead you need to iterate over links so use links.each see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/raQtf/

```
$(function() {
        $('#getResult').click(function() {
             var links = $('a');
            links.each(function(){
                $('#result').append('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
            });

        }); // end click
    }); // end ready
```